# Can't install new apps, all incompatible with Android phone (ZTE Blade)

Tags: google-play-store, installation

After spending a few moments moving some apps from my phone's internal storage to my SD card, I'm no longer able to download/install apps.

Every time I try to get one (like the Wikipedia app) I get the bellow weird alert, saying that my phone is not compatible with the item I'm trying to download.

[image: Screen shoot]

*I can update apps already installed, though.*

How can I solve this problem? This is my first Android phone (ZTE Blade, commonly known as "a5" in Portugal) and I have no idea how to solve this issue. I have Cyanogenmod installed and all caches have been dumped.

**EDIT:**
I've simply uninstalled the updates for the Market app, downgrading it to the 'old' Market and it just worked!! I could easily download and install new apps, but when the Market app re-updated itself automatically, I couldn't download/install any apps again.

Comment: Did you move the 'Market' app?

Comment: Have you tried wiping and reflashing?

Comment: No I didn't, @P.T. I'm not even sure what that is, Demizide, but I'll google it and try it out.

Comment: EDIT: I've simply uninstalled the updates for the Market app, downgrading it to the 'old' Market and it just worked: I could easily download and install new apps, but when the Market app re-updated itself automatically, I couldn't download/install any apps again.

Comment: @JoãoRamos: Don't apologize for your written English. It's better than a lot of native speakers.

Comment: Which Android Version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

When the market re-upates itself. Goto:

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Market

and select 'clear cache'

Now go back into the market and re-signin with your market account. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just get a way to download Mobomarket, and you can use that app to download others, infact it works more or less like google play app. its not necessary to delete anything, unless you cant download the app(mobomarket) itself.